# Use a loop to auto search

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I made a code that can use the cell in A2 to search it in a specific website and pull down the criteria that I need. I'm having trouble making the correct loop for this. Can someone point me in the right direction? (cells from A2 to A1829)

Code:

```
Sub SearchBot()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 
    Dim y As Integer 
    Dim result As String 
    Dim TR As Object, TD As Object
    Dim tbl As Object, obj_tbl As Object
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer  

    objIE.Visible = True  'make IE browser visible
    objIE.navigate "https://capitaliq.com" 

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 

    For i = 1 to 1829
        objIE.document.getElementById("SearchTopBar").Value = _
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value  
        Set oNode = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("iPadHack tmbsearchright")(0) 
        oNode.Click

        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 

        b = 2   

        Dim tblEle As Object
        Set tblEle = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("cTblListBody")(5) 

        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & b).Value = tblEle.innerText
        Debug.Print tblEle.innerText

        b = b + 1 

   Next i 

   objIE.Quit 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not using the loop variable i anywhere, guessing it should be this line:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A").Value
```

change to:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value
```